# can I remove "showing" and "result" words from woocommerce result count?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

can I remove "showing" and "result" words from woocommerce result count?

Now it is like this **showing 1–20 of 7225 results**  but I want it to be like this **1–20 of 7225**

I couldn't find any code about this
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `result-count.php` template from WooCommerce by copying template in your theme.

Example: To override the result-count template, copy: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/result-count.php` to `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/result-count.php`.

remove "showing" and "result" words from [template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/6.8.0/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/result-count.php#L36).

Comment: Thank you for helping me ,  I get to this directory   /home/domain/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/result-count.php  and removed the words

Comment: Welcome :-).   Do not change the plugin template files directly because in future updates of WooCommerce all your customization will be override with plugin update.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the WooCommerce result count before the shop loop and after the shop loop you can use WordPress remove actions to take care of this. No need to adjust core files.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20);
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20);
```

The code can be added to your child theme functions.php